# difference between an API and Webservice in for google maps and google places

Tags: ajax, web-services, api, google-maps, google-places-api

This will probably be down voted but anyway: There are web services for google maps: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/

the name for that is: Google Maps API Web Services
- aren't they two different things?

there is another link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

the name for that is: Google Maps JavaScript API v3

I have a few questions. For the google maps api v3 to work, and for a developer to retrieve information, they would be provided data by a webservice? Can it be explained that the API is wrapped around the webservice?

Why would google provide all these ways of accessing their data?

If using the google API webservice, I should be able to use it using a server side language and/ or scripting language like javascript AJAX?

Comment: the webservices are not accessible to AJAX because of same-origin-restrictions. furthermore requesting the services is only one of many tasks performed the API.

Answer (score 0):

To use the Javascript API you don't need to use the WebService API at all.  You can of course use both together, although more likely you'd use the WebService one server-side, e.g. like the examples they give in Java and Python.  And if you want to use the Webservice API via Javascript you can do that too (although chances are you'd be better of just using the Javascript API).